# It doesn't work correct after I combine two bash shell files into one

Tags: bash, shell, vpn, l2tp

When I executing them sequentially, it works. After I combine them, there comes an error.

The first file(a.sh).

```
# !/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/xl2tpd start | xargs echo
echo "c zju_vpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
```

The second file(b.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3

VPN_SERVER_IP=10.5.1.7
DEFAULT_GW=10.214.16.1
route add $VPN_SERVER_IP gw $DEFAULT_GW eth0
route del default
route add default ppp0
ping github.com
```

After `echo "c zju_vpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control` has been executed, the ppp0 interface will not appear at once. So I write this `sleep 3` in file b.sh.

If I combine them into one(c.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

/etc/init.d/xl2tpd start
echo "c zju_vpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control 

sleep 3

VPN_SERVER_IP=10.5.1.7
DEFAULT_GW=10.214.16.1
route add $VPN_SERVER_IP gw $DEFAULT_GW eth0
route del default
route add default ppp0
ping github.com
```

**There comes the error: SIOCADDRT: No such device.**

There is no ppp0, when I typed `ifconfig`. So when execute `route add default ppp0`, it will be failed, and this is the reason. But I DON'T know why this happened.

Somebody helps me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the VPN will have started after 3 seconds? (Have you tried increasing that to, say, 10 seconds?)

Comment: @duskwuff obviously not. but it doesn't work if i make it little or delete this line

Answer (score 0):

Altering `sleep 3` to `sleep 10`, it works again. This error caused by network delay.